# How do I create an unordered list with inline images replacing the text

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to set up two logos side-by-side (i.e. inline) from an unordered list.  The logo images should replace the text links.

```
<footer>
<ul id="footer-social" class="pull-right">
    <li class="footer-facebook"><a href="#">Become a Facebook Fan</a></li>
    <li class="footer-twitter"><a href="#">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKd6K/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want the images to be links can you not just replace your text there with your <img src="myimagesource"> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KKd6K/2/

Relevant changes: set `li` to block so I could set a width/height to the size of the background image; set the anchors to block as well to allow for text-indent; set background on `li` instead of `a`.

```css
#footer-social li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer-social li a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

#footer-social li.footer-facebook {
    background: url("http://s14.postimg.org/lszvw6dwd/facebook_logo.png") no-repeat;
}

#footer-social li.footer-twitter {
    background: url("http://s12.postimg.org/m5agrq8ah/twitter_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` on your list item `li`:

```css
li{
   display: inline;
}
```

In case you want to keep on using background-images go with `display: inline-block` as it works partly as a block element and you can set `width` and `height` as well:

```css
li{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30px; /* set to width of background-image */
   height: 30px; /* set to height of background-image */
}
```